# Delete picture from UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I have a core data app with some items and imageviews. Now i would like to delete a picked photo from my imageview1 field.

```
imageView1.image = nil
```

and it works and my imageview1 ist empty, but when i save the record my app is crashing with the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Whats the problem? Is it possible to "reset" the imageview1.image?

Comment: What do you mean `when i save the record` ?

Comment: example: i open a record, delete the image and save this. "item!.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView1.image!)"

Comment: Don't do `nil`, instead use a placeholder image. If sending the information on server, send an identity telling the server to not save this image or whatsoever.

Comment: make break point in your code to debug and inspect the actual cause of nil

Comment: hmm i have no idea what is wrong. For the moment i put a empty default picture in my imageview

Answer (score 0):

The error itself tells that while unwrapping an optional value, value found was nil. You need to first check if optional value is nil using if let or guard and unwrap(!) only when they are not nil.

```
If let image = imageView.image {
    Item!.image =UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView1.image!)"
} else {
    Item.image = image(named:  "placeholderimage")
}
```